# What are reasons for "Unable to mount volumes for pod" "timeout expired waiting for ..." in Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am deploying 3 pods to Google Kubernetes Engine.  Two of the pods share ReadOnlyMany bindings to a pre-existing persistent volume, mapped to a gcePersistentDisk.  One of the pods starts.  The other doesn't, and eventually times out with the error "`Unable to mount volumes for pod`"

There are no errors shown under `kubectl describe pv` or `kubectl describe pvc`.  `kubectl describe pvc` shows that each persistent volume claim is bound to the pod that isn't starting.

Relevant configuration:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: configuration
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1G
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  storageClassName: ""
  gcePersistentDisk:
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
    pdName: my-persistent-disk-name
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: kb
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1G
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  storageClassName: ""
  gcePersistentDisk:
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
    pdName: my-persistent-disk-name
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain

---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: content
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1G
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  storageClassName: ""
  gcePersistentDisk:
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
    pdName: my-persistent-disk-name
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: config-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  volumeName: configuration
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1G
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kb-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  volumeName: kb
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1G
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: content-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  volumeName: content
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1G
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: worker
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: esp
          image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1.20.0
          args: [ "-http-port", "8080", ... ]
        - name: workers
          image: my-registry/my-image:my-version
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /config
              subPath: ./config
              readOnly: true
            - name: kb
              mountPath: /kb
              subPath: ./kb
              readOnly: true
            - name: content
              mountPath: /content
              subPath: ./content
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
         - name: config
           persistentVolumeClaim: 
             claimName: config-pvc
             readOnly: true
         - name: kb
           persistentVolumeClaim: 
             claimName: kb-pvc
             readOnly: true
         - name: content
           persistentVolumeClaim:
             claimName: content-pvc
             readOnly: true
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: another-worker
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: another-worker-name
          image: my-registry/my-other-image:my-other-version
         command: ["./run-server.sh", "--path-data", "/config/data/"]
          args: []
          volumeMounts:
            - name: kb
              mountPath: /config
              subPath: ./kb/i2k_context
              readOnly: true
      volumes:        
        - name: kb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: kb-pvc
            readOnly: true
```

The pod named "worker" in the above example should start running.  It doesn't, and eventually shows a timeout error with unmounted and/or unattached volumes.

The pod named "another-worker" starts and runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GKE doesn't permit multiple `PersistentVolume` objects mapped to the same `gcePersistentDisk`, even if all of the volumes and volume claims are ReadOnlyMany.

The reason I had 3 different PV's for the same `gcePersistentDisk` was to allow for flexibility in deployment--the ability to have those three volume bindings actually be different persistent disks.

Since I'm not using the feature at the moment, I changed the `volumes` and `volumeMounts` in the worker pod to use one PVC with different `subPath` and `mountPath` and the pod started up immediately.